# LyX layout for Eurographics

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

Has anyone used/written/heard-of a LyX layout for Eurographics publications? (e.g., Computer Graphics Forum, Symposium on Geometry Processing, etc.)

Eurographics publications provide a LaTeX class/style file, but using it in LyX requires some trial-and-error with Evil Red Text (explicit LaTeX in LyX documents).

In particular, these features cannot be used directly in LyX:

1. Teaser graphics (the figure above the abstract)
2. ACM classification (the `classification` environment)
3. The `proof` and `theorem` environments.
4. The preamble of the document has to be manually edited.

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears such layouts do not exist, I've hacked something. You can have a look at [this site](https://sites.google.com/site/lyxeglayouts/).